# Redux state returns multiple objects of the same name, one inside the other

Tags: react-redux

I'm studying redux and I managed to call the state of a reducert inside my application.
However, the shared state has several objects with the same name inside and until I get to the array I want, it's a very strange path: ***course.course.course.modules?.map***
I don't understand why and I don't know exactly how to solve it.

**Reducers ->**

**course.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {

  modules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Iniciando com react",
      lessons: [
        { id: 1, title: "video01" },
        { id: 2, title: "video02" },
        { id: 3, title: "video03" },
        { id: 4, title: "video04" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Aprendendo react",
      lessons: [
        { id: 1, title: "video01" },
        { id: 2, title: "video02" },
        { id: 3, title: "video03" },
        { id: 4, title: "video04" }
      ]
    }
  ]

};

export const course = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => state;
```

**index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { course } from './course';

export const Reducers = combineReducers({
  course
});
```

**Store ->**
**index.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Reducers } from '../reducers';

export const Store = createStore(Reducers);
```

**Component ->**

**videoSideBar**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function VideoSideBar(course) {
  console.log(course);
  return (
    <aside>
      {
        course.course.course.modules?.map(module => (
          <div key={module.id}>
            <strong>{module.title}</strong>
            <ul>
              {
                module.lessons?.map(leassons => (
                  <li key={leassons.id}>{leassons.title}</li>
                ))
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </aside>
  );
}

export default connect(state => ({ course: state }))(VideoSideBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, please let your reducer state to be an empty array while you combine your reducer and not object inside array , cuz if you combine and you let your initalstate to be an initialState:{course:[]}, it gonna be course of course :

code example using Redux-ToolKit sliceCreator

// Slice
if you dont want object show multiple time :

```
let lastId = 0;
const projectslice = createSlice({
  name: 'Projects',
  initialState:[],
  reducers: {
    PROJECT_ADDED: (projects, action) => {
      projects.push({ id: ++lastId, name: action.payload });
    },
  },
});
export const { PROJECT_ADDED } = projectslice.actions;
export default projectslice.reducer;
```

if you want project to show nested then you do it in this way :

```
// Slice
let lastId = 0;
const projectslice = createSlice({
  name: 'Projects',
  initialState:{projects:[]},
  reducers: {
    PROJECT_ADDED: (projects, action) => {
      projects.push({ id: ++lastId, name: action.payload });
    },
  },
});
export const { PROJECT_ADDED } = projectslice.actions;
export default projectslice.reducer;
```